# how does image rotation work in this function

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, kaggle

I can't understand the code starting from #LIST DEST PIXEL INDICES, I don't get why the and x and y
are the way they are, why aren't they starting from 0,0 instead of DIM//2. From my understanding, this function transforms the image by "inverse" transforming the destination pixels and plugging the original pixels in the destination pixels positions.

get_mat(*args) returns a 3x3 matrix that does various transformations, pretend it is a rotation matrix
take IMAGE_SIZE[0] as 224

this is part of Chris Deotte Kaggel notebook https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/rotation-augmentation-gpu-tpu-0-96

```
def transform(image,label):
    # input image - is one image of size [dim,dim,3] not a batch of [b,dim,dim,3]
    # output - image randomly rotated, sheared, zoomed, and shifted
    DIM = IMAGE_SIZE[0]
    XDIM = DIM%2 #fix for size 331
    
    rot = 15. * tf.random.normal([1],dtype='float32')
    shr = 5. * tf.random.normal([1],dtype='float32') 
    h_zoom = 1.0 + tf.random.normal([1],dtype='float32')/10.
    w_zoom = 1.0 + tf.random.normal([1],dtype='float32')/10.
    h_shift = 16. * tf.random.normal([1],dtype='float32') 
    w_shift = 16. * tf.random.normal([1],dtype='float32') 
  
    # GET TRANSFORMATION MATRIX
    m = get_mat(rot,shr,h_zoom,w_zoom,h_shift,w_shift) 

    # LIST DESTINATION PIXEL INDICES
    x = tf.repeat( tf.range(DIM//2,-DIM//2,-1), DIM )
    y = tf.tile( tf.range(-DIM//2,DIM//2),[DIM] )
    z = tf.ones([DIM*DIM],dtype='int32')
    idx = tf.stack( [x,y,z] )
    
    # ROTATE DESTINATION PIXELS ONTO ORIGIN PIXELS
    idx2 = K.dot(m,tf.cast(idx,dtype='float32'))
    idx2 = K.cast(idx2,dtype='int32')
    idx2 = K.clip(idx2,-DIM//2+XDIM+1,DIM//2)
    
    # FIND ORIGIN PIXEL VALUES           
    idx3 = tf.stack( [DIM//2-idx2[0,], DIM//2-1+idx2[1,]] )
    d = tf.gather_nd(image,tf.transpose(idx3))
        
    return tf.reshape(d,[DIM,DIM,3]),label
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an affine transform of an image done the simple way(without multisampling), i.e. for all of destination pixels find corresponding pixel in source array and take its value.

destination pixel coorinates are put on a list `idx`, which is the transformed with matrix `m`, then they are cast into integers, and culled to image size.

`idx3` is assembled from reverse-offset components (x,y) of source coorinates and used to index original image

> why aren't they starting from 0,0 instead of DIM//2

(0,0) is top left corner of an image *data array*. When thinking of matrix transform you usually think that (0,0) point lies at the center of an image, and thus an offset

Comment: But since 0,0 is the center why did he start with x=112, y= -112, (assuming IMAGE_SIZE[0] was 224) instead of -112, 112, shouldn't the first x, y basically represent the top left destination pixel and so on? appreciate your response :)

Comment: oh never mind, it is the same thing still, just switch the reverse-offset part, thanks